# Extend background beyond div element

Tags: html, css, background, image

Is it possible to extend a `background` element in a div outside of the div frame?

And a follow-up question pertaining to a workaround I've found:

I've put an `<img>` in my HTML code positioned behind my main content. That displays the whole background image correctly, but there are scroll bars extending the full length of the image and the of course the image is selectable. Is there a way to remove the scroll bars and make that image non-selectable?

The reason I'm not putting the background image in the `body` style of the CSS is because I want the background to be attached to my content when the browser window is resized.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an additional wrapper `<div>`, and set the background-image on that.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: No.

Question 2: Use the `background-image` property instead of `<img>`. You can place that in a containing `<div>` behind your content, or in the same box as your content. Using `background-image` will not give you any scrollbars.

Comment: Won't the background be clipped/contained by the `div` size unless I specify a width and height for it that matches the image dimensions? And once I specify those dimensions won't scroll bars appear?

Comment: It will be clipped, yes. If scrollbars appear, it's because the of the content overflow, not the background image. The clipping shouldn't really be a problem (it's usually desirable), but then, I can't visualize what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible to extend a background element in a div outside of the div frame"

You can give the illusion that it does simply by adjusting margin and padding values of 2  div's. It's pure CSS, the top div can grow as tall as you want it too.  The bottom div has to be a set height.  I have tested this on multiple browsers and haven't found any issues yet...

```
<div id="top" style="padding:0 0 300px 0; margin:0 auto -700px; background:red;" >
my top content which can grow in height as much as possible.<br /><br />
my top content which can grow in height as much as possible.<br /><br />
my top content which can grow in height as much as possible.<br /><br />
my top content which can grow in height as much as possible.<br /><br />
my top content which can grow in height as much as possible.<br /><br />
my top content which can grow in height as much as possible.<br /><br />
my top content which can grow in height as much as possible.<br /><br />
my top content which can grow in height as much as possible.<br /><br />
</div>

<div id="bottom" style="margin:400px 0 0; padding:0; height:300px;">
my bottom content at a set height - required!<br /><br />
</div>
```

Hope this helps!  And here is an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/L6uDW/1/) so that you can see what it looks like right away

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using that image background from CSS and then other elements will not auto resize?

Comment: If I use the `background` feature in CSS, the image does not "follow" the content when the window is resized. My content is centered via auto margins.

Comment: even if you set background:center center no-repeat url(where your image is)

Answer (score 0):

I may not be seeing in my head exactly what you want... but there are CSS attributes to remove scrollbars from items, just use the overflow property and set it to hidden.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow

If you are just trying to prevent scrollbars on the DIV that is.  If you know the size of the image, or it's always going to be the same just set the DIV width and height to be the same as the image and it should display it all.

As far as I know there is no way to make the background content larger than the item displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your background image outside of your division, but use CSS positioning to keep it in the right place when you resize the browser. A common solution is that the background position is set to center and so is the division, which keeps them in the same place.